# Greedy Cyclic Group Orders

Tags: finite-groups, prime-numbers, algorithms

Any group of order $n$ is cyclic if and only if $n$ is square-free and no prime factor of $n$ is congruent to one modulo any other prime factor of $n$.*  Thus, the smallest such $n$ divisible by two primes is $3\cdot5=15$, the smallest divisible by three primes is $255=3\cdot5\cdot17$, etc.  Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression guarantees that given any such $n$ we can always find a multiple of $n$ containing an additional prime factor, that also has this property.  (Just take the sequences with steps of size $n$ starting with a number that is coprime to $n$ and not congruent to $1$ mod $n$.)

This there are such numbers $n$ with as many prime factors as you please.  And it isn't too difficult to construct them by the greedy method of looking for the next prime that isn't $1$ mod any primes already selected.  But it seems unlikely this will always give the smallest $n$ corresponding to a given number of prime factors.  Is there a way (more elegant than sheer brute force) to determine for each $k$ the *smallest* $n$ that is a square-free product of $k$ distinct primes none of which is congruent to $1$ mod one of the others?

* If you are interested in the group theory argument, square-free is an obvious necessity, and if $p$ divides $q-1$, then there is a non-abelian semi-direct product.  The converse is a consequence of the counting portion of Philip Hall's theorems..

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence, given that there are cyclic and non-cyclic groups of order 4.

Comment: 4 is certainly not square-free

Comment: He said "if and only if".

Comment: Pretty sure he meant "There is only one group of order $n$ if and only if $n$ is square free..."

Comment: Is it not the case that (there is only one group of order n) if and only if (n is prime)? If n is not prime there are at least two abelian groups of that order. I'm not trying to be dense, but I'm not an algebraist.

Comment: If $n$ is prime there is obviously only one group of order $n$, but the converse is false. As C Monsour mentionned, there is only one group of order 15.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That was a silly misremembering of the CRT. Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Your numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A264907 where there is also a Mathematica program to calculate them. But it must be hard to do, as only the first 12 terms are given.

Comment: Thanks.  At least the list confirms my suspicion that a greedy search won't keep finding the minimal examples.  When I have the time I'll review the code to see if there is more to it than brute force.